# Rails: ActiveRecord class throws "NameError: uninitialized constant" - Is this a naming issue?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, nameerror

I have a model file called:

```
r_i_o_modules_and_instrument.rb
```

...which contains something like this...

```
class RIOModulesAndInstrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parentmodel
  attr_accessible :attribute_1, :attribute_2, :attribute_3
end
```

The corresponding MySQL table name is:

```
 r_i_o_modules_and_instruments
```

But: In the cosole, from...

```
> RIOModulesAndInstrument.count
```

...I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant RIOModulesAndInstrument
```

Does anybody have a clue what the problem is and ways to solve it? (Is it a naming restriction problem?)

Thanks a lot for helping out!

Comment: I suspect this is not the issue, but what happens if you 'require' the model explicitly?  In the console, for example.

Comment: @ Dave S.: It seems to load correctly, it returns "true". Then, when I try the query "RIOModulesAndInstrument.count" again, it returns: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'mydatabase_development.rio_modules_and_instruments' doesn't exist...

Comment: Hmm, I think we're closing in.  Try setting the table for the class perhaps, via 'set_table_name'.  I think rails is coming up with the wrong answer because of your capitalization.  In essence you're right it's a naming restriction, but ROR relies on convention, and you've stepped just slightly outside the box with your choice here.

Comment: How did you write your migration???

Comment: I have tried creating model `rails g model r_i_o_modules_and_instrument`. Its created table name with `rio_modules_and_instruments` and model file name is `rio_modules_and_instrument.rb`. But in model class name is still `RIOModuleAndInstrument`. This clearly indicates rails follows some convention on `model names`.

Comment: @ Dave S.: I found out that 'set_table_name' was deprecated in v3.2, so I tried and set in the model: self.table_name = "r_i_o_modules_and_instruments". Rebooting the console and doing the mentioned query again, I got the same error again. Strangely enough, when I explicetly/manually "required" the model file, the query worked perfectly (the explicit table name was taken into account)...

Comment: @codeit: I created and executed a .sh file with all the migration code in it (a few thousand models/tables) and the part of the model in question is: rails g model r_i_o_modules_and_instrument attribute_1:string attribute_2:string attribute_3:string ... --no-test-framework
But strangely enough, my table name is still as mentioned: r_i_o_modules_and_instruments

Comment: @TomDogg I have posted answer. Try that and let me know the error if u don't get it work.

Comment: @TomDogg Sorry, which is your rails version?? Did u try my answer??

Comment: @codeit: Yes, I tried your answer (but with "self.table_name = '...'" instead of 'set_table_name'). Technically, your workaround works fine (to me, this whole issue seems like a bug in Rails). The only problem I have left is that my model names are generated based on names that already exist. So in this situation, I won't be able to do like you propose... (I'm on Rails 3.2.12)

Comment: @TomDogg you are not changing your model name here. It will remain same as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Change your model file name to `rio_modules_and_instrument.rb`

In model `rio_modules_and_instrument.rb`

```
class RIOModulesAndInstrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "r_i_o_modules_and_instruments" #if you are using rails v > 3.1.0 use self.table_name = "r_i_o_modules_and_instruments"
  belongs_to :parentmodel
  attr_accessible :attribute_1, :attribute_2, :attribute_3
end
```

Comment: The moral of the story: Rails 3.2.12 cannot handle model file names that include a single character which is enclosed by underscores:

a_b_c_something.rb: NOT possible

Comment: @TomDogg Any version of rails not just 3.2.12

Comment: Well, hopefully not future versions ;-) And don't forget to upgrade today - anything older than 3.2.12 has very serious security holes.

Answer (score -4):

### Heading ##try RIOModulesAndInstruments, thats because the active record makes it plural

Comment: ...makes it plural for what exactly? (Not for either model name or model file name, as far as I know... And the MySQL table *is* already in plural.)

Comment: The class and filename are singular, the table is plural, so no problem there.